# ajax post array get type error

Tags: php, jquery

I post array via ajax like:

```
console.log(srcarray); //["16.png", "17.png", "19.png", "18.png"]

$.ajax({
    type: "POST", url: "update.php",
    data: {srcarray: srcarray}
})
```

get error:

```
TypeError: Type error       jquery-1.10.1.min.js:6
```

I tried add `processData: false, contentType: false,` seems not work, won't show error  but can't post data to php....

How can I fix this?
Appreciate your help. Thanks

**UPDATE UPDATE**
found the error line:
`t = x.isFunction(t) ? t() : null == t ? "" : t, i[i.length] = encodeURIComponent(e) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(t)`

**UPDATE**

the array comes

below code in container each function   so console.log(content_img_arr_merge)
will get result :

["16.png", "17.png", "19.png", "18.png"]
["0.png"]
["0.png"]
[]
[]

```
$.each(content_img_arr_merge, function (index, value) {
    content_img_arr_merge[index] = value.replace("u_img/"+id+"/", "");
});
console.log(content_img_arr_merge);
```

If I change the code test:

```
$.each(content_img_arr_merge, function (index, value) {
    content_img_arr_merge[index] = value.replace("u_img/"+id+"/", "");
});
console.log(content_img_arr_merge); 
content_img_arr_merge = ["16.png", "17.png", "19.png", "18.png"];
```

Then it doesn't shows the error...

Comment: Are you sure that's the line that's causing your error?

Comment: can you use a non minified version of jQuery and check the line throwing the error

Comment: yes I'm sure, if I remove the data srcarray only post others all works fine

Comment: yes I use console.log before ajax get  `["16.png", "17.png", "19.png", "18.png"]`

Comment: please have a see update the question

Comment: @ArunPJohny  I found the error line update in question   `t = x.isFunction(t) ? t() : null == t ? "" : t, i[i.length] = encodeURIComponent(e) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(t)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17876165/1575921
use `$.get()`   `data: { "images" : array.get() }`

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding quotes,

i.e,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", url: "update.php",
    data: {'srcarray': srcarray} //added quotes here 'srcarray'
});
```

or simply pass the data array only,

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", url: "update.php",
        data: srcarray
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for reply!  my code is like : data: {id: id, visible: visible,...} how to only  the array??   also I try add quote still same result...

Comment: but there is no quotes in the code snippet you posted above. Can you just replace the code with above one ??

Comment: On which line yo get this error ? It seems there is no error in this code.. may be  anywhere else and not related to this ajax post

Comment: there's not show which line  error in my code, but only if I add this array to post data, then will happen... I updated the question shows type error in which line error in jquery

Answer (score -1):

The data arg to $.ajax has to be a string, or a "[PlainObject](http://api.jquery.com/Types#PlainObject)" (basically, a simple array created with "{}" or "new Object()", it appears).

You probably want to pass the srcarray arg through JSON.stringify, such as in this code snippet:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", url: "update.php",
    data: {srcarray: JSON.stringify(srcarray)}
})
```

That way you'll have a string which should be easily converted back to an array on the other end.

Comment: The documentation of `PlainObject` doesn't say that the values have to be strings. If the value is an array, I thought jQuery would post it similar to a form with `srcarray[]` elements.

Comment: From http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/: _If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting_

Comment: I tried JSON.stringfy but get another error .... JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures.