# Post value via ajax to php

Tags: php, jquery

I trying to post some value via ajax to php then php print send back js console.log, have problem:

build array( I'm doubt below I made is array??)

```
$('.eachcontainer').each(function(){
        var arr = $(this).find('img').map(function(){
            return $(this).attr('src');
        });
        console.log(arr);
        // result:
        // ["16.png", "17.png", "19.png", "18.png"]
        // ["0.png"]
        // ["0.png"]
        // []
        // []
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", url: "update.php",
            data: arr
        }).done(function(msg){
            console.log(msg);
        });
});
```

php

```
print_r($_POST);
```

js come back console.log

```
Array
(
    [undefined] => 
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
    [undefined] => 
)
```

Why this does not work? How can i fix it?

Also, I tried to change the syntax in my ajax function  `data: {arr: arr}` but this didn't work either.
Error message:
 `TypeError: Type error       jquery-1.10.1.min.js:6`
Found error line in jquery-1.10.1.min.js:6:
 `t = x.isFunction(t) ? t() : null == t ? "" : t, i[i.length] = encodeURIComponent(e) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(t)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to call `arr.get()` to get the `jquery.map` result back as a regular javascript array. Then you can pass it to the ajax data paramter as:

```
data: { "images" : arr.get() }
```

So the full ajax call would look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", url: "update.php",
    data: { "images" : arr.get() }
}).done(function(msg){
    console.log(msg);
});
```

You can then read the array back in php as:

```
$images = $_POST['images'];
```

Answer (score 1):

you haven't constructed proper key&value pair using your data, if you want to pass a raw stream of data then set `processData: false` and capture with `php://input`

```
 var arr = $(this).find('img').map(function(){
            return $(this).attr('src');
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", url: "update.php",
            data: arr,
            processData: false,
        }).done(function(msg){
            console.log(msg);
        });
```

on the php side

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Comment: if set processData: false  will effect another data?  because I try to post another data:{x: x, y: y} sametime

Comment: It will only affect the current request. Subsequent requests will only be affected when you set their processData option to false

Comment: then how do I wrote the syntax is correct : data{x: x, y: y, arr: arr}        php   print $_POST['x']; print $_POST['y']; print file_get_contents("php://input");